# To assign NULL to field or not

Tags: java, spring

Any difference on these lines?

```
1.    @Autowired
      private MyClass obj;

2.    @Autowired
      private  MyClass obj = null;

3.    @Autowired
      private  MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

Obviously, the third one is a bad practice.

Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference: The instance is injected by the container regardless what what you assign to it.

Option 1 is the best and most common style used.